# Ways to access Microsoft Graph API

Tags: java, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access Microsoft Graph API using the following code in Java :-

```
    String url_str = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/";
    String access_token = getAccessToken();
    url = new URL(url_str);
    con = ( HttpURLConnection )url.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", access_token);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
    con.connect();

    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream() ));
    String str = null;
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        str += line;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Currently I am getting JSON String which i will need to parse further. All I want to know is there any other way which will reduce the pain of deserialization or something more better.

Comment: A Java client library for Microsoft Graph is on its way and will be available soon. Read the tea leaves at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android/issues/62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not aware of any Java SDK for Microsoft Graph. However, you can use [jsonutil](http://jsonutils.com/) to generate your java objects which will reduce at least some work.

**Edit:**
As [mentioned by Pranay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49033754/1163423), a Java SDK is released, you should use this instead.

Comment: This is no longer the best advice - use the Java SDK as noted in the other answers instead.

Answer (score 5):

Update on Martin answer, Java SDK is released and available for public preview :- 
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java.

Answer (score 1):

Another Java client for Microsoft Graph is [odata-client](https://github.com/davidmoten/odata-client) which has support for the Graph v1.0, Beta, Graph Explorer endpoints and for Dynamics CRM and Analytics for Devops OData services. I was an early collaborator on the *msgraph-sdk-java* library and the problems there led me to create what I think is a much stronger product. In particular *odata-client-msgraph* (and the sibling libraries)

- uses immutability
- detects changes for patching
- models inheritance
- extensively uses fluent builders
- implements java.util.Stream on collections
- provides easier authentication
- offers better type safety
- has very clean generated code
- has better discoverability
- has decent unit test coverage of API interactions
- offers email helpers for that part of the API
- is released very frequently in line with frequent service updates

Answer (score 0):

You should use the newly-released Java SDK for Microsoft Graph. More details were recently posted [here](https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-java-sdk-preview-2), and the github repo for the SDK is [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java).